# Getting the first element of a "vstack"-ed array vs a predifined array.Same array, different results?

Tags: numpy

I belive these should have the same result, but it is not.

```
import numpy as np

a=np.empty((0,9))
a=np.vstack((a,[1,2,3,4,"hello",6,7,8,9]))
print(a[0])
```

result:['1' '2' '3' '4' 'hello' '6' '7' '8' '9']

But if I do it this way:

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array([1,2,3,4,"hello",6,7,8,9])
print(a[0])
```

result:1

Why is there a difference? Isn't it the same array?

Thank you for the answers in advance.

Comment: `vstack` applies `np.atleast_2d([your_list])` before joining it to the `(0,9)` array - on axis=0.  Thus it joins a (0,9) with (1,9) array, resulting in a (1,9).  `vstack` docs tries to be explicit about that action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not the same.

Your first example results in an array of shape `(1, 9)`, whereas your second example is an array of shape `(9,)`, which can be confirmed as below:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.empty((0,9))
a = np.vstack((a,[1,2,3,4,"hello",6,7,8,9]))
print(a.shape) # result is: (1, 9)

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,"hello",6,7,8,9])
print(a.shape) # result is: (9,)
```

An array with shape `(1, 9)` can be thought of as an array (of length 1) that contains arrays (each of length 9). Therefore, in your example, `a[0]` gives you the first of these arrays of length 9, which is `[1,2,3,4,"hello",6,7,8,9]`.